# Performing async function on each element in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

So I have an array of URLs

I want to pull the html from each (for which I am using [restler](https://github.com/danwrong/restler) node.js library)

Then select some of that data to act on via jquery (for which I am using [cheerio](https://github.com/MatthewMueller/cheerio) node.js library)

The code I have works, but duplicates the pulled data by however many URLS there are.
I am doing this in Node but suspect it's a generalized Javascript matter that I don't understand too well.

```
url.forEach(function(ugh){
    rest.get(ugh).on('complete', function(data) {
        $ = cheerio.load(data);
        prices.push($(".priceclass").text());
        //i only want this code to happen once per item in url array
        //but it happens url.length times per item
        //probably because i don't get events or async very well
    });
});
```

So if there are 3 items in the 'url' array, the 'prices' array with the data I want will have 9 items. Which I don't want

--EDIT:

Added a counter to verify that the 'complete' callback was executing array-length times per array item.

```
x=0;
url.forEach(function(ugh){
    rest.get(ugh).on('complete', function(data) {
        var $ = cheerio.load(data);
        prices.push($(".priceclass").text());
        console.log(x=x+1);
    });
});
```

Console outputs 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9

I was thinking that I might be going about this wrong. I've been trying to push some numbers onto an array, and then outside the callbacks do something with that array.

Anyways it seems clear that >1 restler eventlisteners aren't gonna work together at all.

Maybe rephrasing the question would help:
How would I scrape a number of URLs, then act on that data?

Currently looking into request & async libraries, via code from the extinguished [node.io library](https://github.com/chriso/node.io)

Comment: Typo: `url.forEach()` <-- and `prices.push($(".priceclass").text();` <--

Comment: you have an un-matched `(`

Comment: Oh- I modified the code some in pasting here. No typos in the working code.

Comment: `$ = cheerio.load(data);` is a bad idea if you're using jquery. Please click "edit" below the taglist in your question and fix the typos.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Typos edited out. RE: "bad idea": I'm using a server-side implementation of jquery, and that's the "preferred method" !

Comment: By "jQuery", do you mean Cheerio? It's not really jQuery, it's just middleware that looks and acts a little bit like jQuery?

Comment: And, if you have three URL's, each with three `.priceclass`, you will of course get nine entries in the array? What do you really want, just the three from the first URL, the first ( second or third? ) element from each URL etc ?

Comment: adeneo: Yes I mean Cheerio not jQuery. Thanks, deleted that tag. And I've realized that I'm pushing arrays into an array, which is not exactly what I want. If each url has ten .priceclasses, the ideal is 'prices' array will be 30 items long

Comment: `prices.push($(".media-heading.pull-right").text().replace(/,/g, "").split("$").filter(Number));` is the actual Cheerio selector I'm using. It gives an array while the `.text()` example I replaced it with, for simplicity's sake, does not- apologies

Comment: "9 items" in the results array sounds like a bug in the `rest.get(ugh).on` function (not because of your usage). Can you confirm that the "complete" callback is invoked 9 times - 3 times per every of the 3 urls? Apart from that, I'd suggest `var $ = …`.

Comment: Thanks @Bergi for noting that my usage didn't seem wrong. Was worried I was doing something in an obviously wrong way. Edited the question with a confirmation that the callbacks get repeated

Answer (score 0):

To answer the rephrased question, [scramjet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) is great for this if you use ES6+ and node which I assume you do:

#### How would I scrape a number of URLs, then act on that data?

Install the packages:

```
npm install scramjet node-fetch --save
```

Scramjet works on streams - it will read your list of url's and make each url a stream that you can work with as simple as with Array's. node-fetch is a simple node module that follows the standard Fetch Web API.

A simple example that also reads the url's from a file, assuming you store them one per line:

```
const {StringStream} = require("scramjet");
const fs = require("fs")
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

fs.createReadStream(process.argv[2])     // open the file for reading
    .pipe(new StringStream())            // redirect it to scramjet stream
    .split("\n")                         // split line by line
    .map((url) => fetch(url))            // get the URL from the endpoint
    .map((resp) => JSON.parse(resp))     // parse the response
    .toArray()                           // accumulate the data into an Array
    .then(
         (data) => doYourStuff(data),    // do the calculations
         (err) => showErrorMessage(data)
    )
```

Thanks to the way scramjet works, you needn't worry about error handling (all errors are caught automatically) and managing simultaneous requests. If you can parse the files url by url, then you can also make this very memory and resources efficient - as it won't ready and try to fetch all the items at once, but it will do some work in parallel.

There are more examples and the full API description in the [scramjet docs](https://github.com/signicode/scramjet#api-docs).